# What is meant by A determine BC in functional dependency. How the validity of this statement will be checked

Tags: logic, databases, classification

We use notation A determines BC in a database for functional dependency. Same way we use equations in mathematics which shows dependency of variables. We have inference rules in logics,  functions in mathematics, set theoritic notations and functional dependency in DBMS.
We have relational algebra, tuple calculus. We use notations in our presentations. What types of presentations we are using in functional dependency in DBMS.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What do you mean by "the mathematical logical validity" of a functional dependency?  What do you mean by the classification of them? I suggest providing more context and motivation.  Why do you ask?  How do you plan to evaluate answers? Where did you encounter this question?

Comment: I understand all terms in this question except 'presentations'. What do you mean by a 'presentation'?

Comment: Presentation means style of writing notations and it's meaning. Example 1. A determine BC in functional dependency 2. y = x in mathematics 3. y = a .and. b  in mathematical logic, 4. C = A U B in set theory etc.

Comment: y = x is a presentation in mathematics , when we use this notation in DBMS for functional dependency then we will write x determine y. The term "determine" is  used as a general term in DBMS. Can we explain the term "determine" in a specific way to Prove validity of statement to operators and operations.